# Calculate route using only specified routes with HERE

Tags: overlay, here-api

I want to calculate a route from A to B using only a subset of the routes available in a city, as long as it is possible (if A or B is not on the subset of roads I still need to calculate the route). I tried to use `avoidareas` but it's quite difficult to define rectangles to avoid outside of the roads (and I saw somewhere the number of boxes is limited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please explain what do you mean by "subset of the routes". Do you mean to avoid a particular kind of road? 
if you want to always include a certain road(s) you can always use waypoints to direct the route through  those roads. Generally, Routing algorithms are designed to "avoid" not "prefer" an area.

Various examples on how to avoid a rectangle(s) is explained here- https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/example-route-avoiding-an-area.html

How to use a waypoint is explained here - https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html

How to avoid a certain road type is explained here - https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/avoiding-certain-road-types.html

Comment: My use case is that I want a route going through a city but only using some of the roads in the city. If the start/end is outside the city and I can say "here are the roads you can take", then it will trace the route on these roads only

Comment: if you want to avoid certain features, like roads with high traffic, or roads with tunnels, toll roads etc.., our avoid options(third link in the above answer) can be used. But I do not see a reason to limit the end user to only a few roads through the city. The task of  the routing algorithm to provide the best course across the city. Can you please define the problem in terms of some parameters which define "best" for your particular use case.

Comment: Selecting only a particular set of road based on the "area/location" of the road is not supported. You have to define your "choice"  in terms of parameter so that all other option except your choice can be avoided and then you can give it as input to routing algorithm. But again, can you explain why do you want to limit the users to certain roads?